# Calculating the limit of (1+1/n)^n

Tags: c

I have to make a program that calculates the limit of *(1+1/n)<sup>n</sup>* (as n approaches infinity) with a precision of epsilon. Here is what I've tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    double e = exp(1), eps, t = 1;
    scanf("%lf", eps);
    while ((e - t) > eps) {
        t = pow(1 + (1 / (float)i), i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%lf", t);
}
```

For the input `0.001`, the output should be `2.682435` but this program doesn't print anything. I'm a beginner in C and I don't understand why this isn't working and it's driving me insane.

**EDIT:** I realized it was because I forgot to add the ampersand in `scanf`, but the program outputs the wrong number, it shows `2.717296` instead of `2.682435`.

Comment: scanf("%lf", &eps) is right usage.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on the proper use of `scanf()`.

Comment: @Emreİriş I didn't even realize I didn't include it. Thanks. Still it doesn't output the right thing, it outputs `2.717296` instead of `2.682435`...

Comment: And `%f` is correct for printf rather than `%lf`.

Comment: @grokestray  e equals 2.7182818284... so your output seems to be correct to me.

Comment: @Emreİriş for `eps=0.001`? Shouldn't it be `2.682435`?

Comment: I'm sure using the result of `exp(1)` in the comparison is cheating. You should be comparing the two most recent values with each other.

Comment: @grokestray Firstly you need to understand computers are not real mathematicians, some mathematical operations are surely rounded up, that is why expectation and result is different.

Comment: May I ask where does the value of 2.682435 you are talking about come from?

Comment: There is absolutely no need for scanf in this problem.  It is better to take the parameter as a command line argument: `int main(int argc, char **argv) { double eps = argc > 1 ? strtod(argv[1], NULL) : .001; ...`

Comment: @Bob__ it was the result of one of the test cases given by my professor. Could it be wrong?

Comment: No what is wrong is the fact that you compare to the actual value of e.

Comment: The professor's code converges too soon because of accumulated errors. This is an abysmal way to calculate _e_.

Comment: Using `float` math with `1+(1/(float)i)`, and `double` math elsewhere (`(e-t)>eps`, `pow()`) unnecessarily complicates things.  Use `double` math throughout: `1+(1/(double)i)`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the discrepancy between the result values: You are comparing the current value to the exepcted value, which, realistically, you can't know, because the point of the exercise it to calculate it.

Instead, your epsilon is the difference between the previous and the current value: The values are approaching *e* in ever decreasing intervals. Once this difference is small enough, stop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double eps = 0.001;
    double t = 2.0;
    int i = 2;
    
    for (;;) {
        double tprev = t;
        
        t = pow(1.0 + (1.0 / i), i);
        
        if (fabs(tprev - t) < eps) break;
        i++;
    }

    printf("%d: %f\n", i, t);
}
```

This will yield the value 2.682435. (You can of course try several epsilons and see how big the relative error to the actual *e* is.)

Comment: I tried implementing your solution using my own knowledge, but it doesn't show the right thing at all... Here is the code: https://onlinegdb.com/HyEABjUfu . What did I do wrong?

Comment: Well, you set `t2 = t`, which means `t2 - t == 0`and `fabs(t2 - t) > eps` will never be true. (For a positive `eps`, anyway.) You could probably calculate a `delta` and use it in a "proper" `while` loop, [see here](https://ideone.com/iDBYyL).

Comment: Do you mean that it's stuck in an infinite loop? Becuase it itsn't, it just shows `2.000000`. Can you show me how you would do it with a while loop? Because I'm really puzzled as to why it doesn't work, since to me it's basically the same thing as your code but with a while loop....

Comment: No, quite the opposite: It's a loop-that-never-executes, because the looping condition is false from the outset. And 2.0 is the value that you set explicitly. (You can step through the program in a debugger and look at the current values as you go.)

Comment: Oooh, I get it. Can't believe I didn't realise that. Thank you.

Comment: I've put code with a `while` alternative in the "see here" link above.

Answer (score 2):

(This is a supplementary answer to provide additional information.)

Regarding the inaccuracies between the calculated limit and the real value of the limit (*e*), this is because the `pow(1+1/(double)i, i)` expression becomes more and more inaccurate as `i` increases, so it slowly converges to the wrong value. The `1+1/(double)i` part becomes slightly less accurate as `i` increases and raising the inaccurate value to the power `i` magnifies the inaccuracy.

Since the limit of (1+1/*n*)<sup>*n*</sup> as *n* tends to positive infinity is known to be Euler's number, *e*, the limit could be calculated more accurately using the infinite series summing 1/*n*! values for *n* from 0 to infinity. This series converges much faster than the successive members of the (1+1/*n*)<sup>*n*</sup> sequence.

An example implementation is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    double eps,t=1,f=1,pre;
    scanf("%lf", &eps);
    do
    {
        i++;
        pre=t;
        f/=i;
        t+=f;
        printf("%d: (%.29lf) %.29lf\n",i, f, t);
    } while (fabs(t-pre)>eps);
    printf("\nFinal result: %.29lf\n",t);
    printf("\nDifference from previous result: %.29lf\n", fabs(pre-t));
    printf("Difference from Euler's number e: %.29lf\n", fabs(M_E - t));
    printf("(Euler's number e: %.29lf)\n", M_E);
}
```

Running with an input of 0.001:

```
1: (1.00000000000000000000000000000) 2.00000000000000000000000000000
2: (0.50000000000000000000000000000) 2.50000000000000000000000000000
3: (0.16666666666666665741480812812) 2.66666666666666651863693004998
4: (0.04166666666666666435370203203) 2.70833333333333303727386009996
5: (0.00833333333333333321768510160) 2.71666666666666634100124610995
6: (0.00138888888888888894189432843) 2.71805555555555544700041536998
7: (0.00019841269841269841252631712) 2.71825396825396836675281520002

Final result: 2.71825396825396836675281520002

Difference from previous result: 0.00019841269841291975239983003
Difference from Euler's number e: 0.00002786020507672404278309841
(Euler's number e: 2.71828182845904509079559829843)
```

Running with an input of 0:

```
1: (1.00000000000000000000000000000) 2.00000000000000000000000000000
2: (0.50000000000000000000000000000) 2.50000000000000000000000000000
3: (0.16666666666666665741480812812) 2.66666666666666651863693004998
4: (0.04166666666666666435370203203) 2.70833333333333303727386009996
5: (0.00833333333333333321768510160) 2.71666666666666634100124610995
6: (0.00138888888888888894189432843) 2.71805555555555544700041536998
7: (0.00019841269841269841252631712) 2.71825396825396836675281520002
8: (0.00002480158730158730156578964) 2.71827876984127003723301641003
9: (0.00000275573192239858925109506) 2.71828152557319224769116772222
10: (0.00000027557319223985893569742) 2.71828180114638451314590383845
11: (0.00000002505210838544172022387) 2.71828182619849290091451621265
12: (0.00000000208767569878681001866) 2.71828182828616871091753637302
13: (0.00000000016059043836821615926) 2.71828182844675936280509631615
14: (0.00000000001147074559772972612) 2.71828182845823018709552343353
15: (0.00000000000076471637318198174) 2.71828182845899490871488524135
16: (0.00000000000004779477332387386) 2.71828182845904287034954904811
17: (0.00000000000000281145725434552) 2.71828182845904553488480814849
18: (0.00000000000000015619206968586) 2.71828182845904553488480814849

Final result: 2.71828182845904553488480814849

Difference from previous result: 0.00000000000000000000000000000
Difference from Euler's number e: 0.00000000000000044408920985006
(Euler's number e: 2.71828182845904509079559829843)
```

Note: The value reported for "`Euler's number e`" in the above output is actually the value of the closest number to *e* that can be represented in a `double`, printed to 29 decimal places. The actual value of *e* to 29 decimal places is slightly less: 2.71828182845904523536028747135 (differing from the 16th decimal place onward). The value calculated by the program above with an epsilon input of 0 is actually the smallest number greater than *e* that can be represented in a `double`, printed to 29 decimal places (differing from *e* from the 16th decimal place onward).

Comment: Nice work.  The calculated answer is within 1 ULP of _e_. `M_E` is within 0.5 ULP of _e_.  Sometimes summing the smallest terms first helps achieve the best answer. A reverse summation leads to the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scanf needs pointers, not actual variable. So you may want to refer to address of eps -> &eps.
I suggest also to add \n to printf, for adding a new line.
Here is an example

https://onlinegdb.com/KIHgtcb25

Comment: To post a script from OnlineGDB you have to use the link generated when clicking the `Share` button

Comment: I was sure I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a supplementary answer to provide additional information to show the slight advantage of summing smallest terms first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifndef M_E
  #define M_E 2.7182818284590452353602874713527
#endif

double e_helper(double f, int i) {
  if (1 + f == 1) {
    return f;
  }
  i++;
  return f + e_helper(f / i, i);
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%.17f Machine e\n", M_E);
  printf("%.17f Calculated e\n", e_helper(1.0, 0));
  printf("2.71828182845904523 e\n");
  printf("%.17f Machine e next\n", nextafter(M_E, 3));
}
```

Output

```
2.71828182845904509 Machine e
2.71828182845904509 Calculated e
2.71828182845904523 e
2.71828182845904553 Machine e next
```